# How to pass a container of unique_ptrs where container, ptrs and objects are not modifiable?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, const-correctness

I have a container `vector` that has `std::unique_ptr` of some type.  I want to return that container, but also want to enforce that I don't want the container, pointer or the object pointed at to be modifiable.  I also don't want to make some paralel copy of this object.  My alias type would be something like:

```
using container_t = vector<std::unique_ptr<my_type_t>>
```

So I'm thinking that I could make another alias like this:

```
using const_container_t = const vector<std::unique_ptr<const my_type_t>>
```

and do a `reinterpret_cast` for my getter:

```
const_container_t& encompassing_type::get_container() const
{
  return reinterpret_cast<const_container_t&>(m_container);
}
```

I'm thinking that this should work, but I'm wondering if there are any gotchas that I'm not seeing, or if there is some other better way of doing this.

I would also imagine that this might result in duplicate binary code in the final build, but as these are most likely inlined anyway, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I would stay away from `reinterpret_cast` because I am not sure if this is undefined behavior.

Comment: You might be able to return something like a `span<const my_type_t>` instead

Comment: @Justin Isn't the problem with the `unique_ptr`? So it would have to be `span<unique_ptr<my_type_t>>`, but this wouldn't help since `unique_ptr::operator*` returns a non-const reference.

Comment: @Jens That's why I said, "something like". It couldn't be a `span` itself, but whatever is returned can use the same idea of a `span`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to include boost and `span` wouldn't work, because as @Jens pointed out, a `unique_ptr` doesn't propagate the cv qualifiers.  Also, even if I did include boost, I wouldn't be able to get an actual object reference for each item in the vector, which I would need to allow me to compare relative locations of the object with others in the container.

So I opted instead for writing a wrapper over `std::unique_ptr` which will propagate the cv qualifiers.

The following is an excerpt from my `enable_if.h` file, which I use for the comparison operators to limit how many times I have to write them:

```
namespace detail
{
    // Reason to use an enum class rather than just an int is so as to ensure
    // there will not be any clashes resulting in an ambiguous overload.
    enum class enabler
    {
        enabled
    };
}
#define ENABLE_IF(...) std::enable_if_t<__VA_ARGS__, detail::enabler> = detail::enabler::enabled
#define ENABLE_IF_DEFINITION(...) std::enable_if_t<__VA_ARGS__, detail::enabler>
```

Here is my implementation of c++20's `std::remove_cvref_t`:

```
template <typename T>
using remove_cvref_t = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```

And here is the wrapped unique ptr:

```
template <typename T, typename D = std::default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr_propagate_cv;

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, typename D>
    std::unique_ptr<T, D> const& get_underlying_unique_ptr(unique_ptr_propagate_cv<T, D> const& object)
    {
        return object.ptr;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename D>
class unique_ptr_propagate_cv
{
    template <typename T_, typename D_>
    friend std::unique_ptr<T_, D_> const& detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr<T_, D_>(unique_ptr_propagate_cv<T_, D_> const&);

    using base = std::unique_ptr<T, D>;
    base ptr;
public:
    template <typename...Ts>
    unique_ptr_propagate_cv(Ts&&...args) noexcept : ptr(std::forward<Ts>(args)...) {}

    using element_type           = typename base::element_type;
    using deleter_type           = typename base::deleter_type;

    using pointer                = element_type                *;
    using pointer_const          = element_type const          *;
    using pointer_volatile       = element_type       volatile *;
    using pointer_const_volatile = element_type const volatile *;

    using reference                = element_type                &;
    using reference_const          = element_type const          &;
    using reference_volatile       = element_type       volatile &;
    using reference_const_volatile = element_type const volatile &;

    pointer                get()                noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
    pointer_const          get() const          noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
    pointer_volatile       get()       volatile noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
    pointer_const_volatile get() const volatile noexcept { return ptr.get(); }

    pointer                operator->()                noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
    pointer_const          operator->() const          noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
    pointer_volatile       operator->()       volatile noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
    pointer_const_volatile operator->() const volatile noexcept { return ptr.get(); }

    reference                operator[](size_t index)                noexcept { return ptr.operator[](index); }
    reference_const          operator[](size_t index) const          noexcept { return ptr.operator[](index); }
    reference_volatile       operator[](size_t index)       volatile noexcept { return ptr.operator[](index); }
    reference_const_volatile operator[](size_t index) const volatile noexcept { return ptr.operator[](index); }

    reference                operator*()                noexcept { return ptr.operator*(); }
    reference_const          operator*() const          noexcept { return ptr.operator*(); }
    reference_volatile       operator*()       volatile noexcept { return ptr.operator*(); }
    reference_const_volatile operator*() const volatile noexcept { return ptr.operator*(); }

    template <typename T_>
    unique_ptr_propagate_cv& operator=(T_&& rhs)
    {
        return static_cast<unique_ptr_propagate_cv&>(ptr.operator=(std::forward<T_>(rhs)));
    }

    decltype(auto) get_deleter()            const noexcept { return ptr.get_deleter(); }
                   operator bool()          const noexcept { return ptr.operator bool(); }
    decltype(auto) reset(pointer ptr = pointer()) noexcept {        get_base_nonconst().reset(ptr); }
    decltype(auto) release()                      noexcept { return get_base_nonconst().release();  }

};

template <typename T>
struct is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename D>
struct is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<unique_ptr_propagate_cv<T, D>> : std::true_type {};

namespace detail
{
    inline nullptr_t const& get_underlying_unique_ptr(nullptr_t const& object)
    {
        return object;
    }

    template <typename T, typename D>
    std::unique_ptr<T, D> const& get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<T, D> const& object)
    {
        return object;
    }
}

template <typename L, typename R
    , ENABLE_IF(
           is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<L>>::value
        || is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<R>>::value
    )
>
bool operator==(L&& lhs, R&& rhs) noexcept
{
    return detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<L>(lhs))
        == detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<R>(rhs));
}

template <typename L, typename R
    , ENABLE_IF(
           is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<L>>::value
        || is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<R>>::value
    )
>
auto operator!=(L&& lhs, R&& rhs) noexcept
{
    return detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<L>(lhs))
        != detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<R>(rhs));
}

template <typename L, typename R
    , ENABLE_IF(
           is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<L>>::value
        || is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<R>>::value
    )
>
bool operator<=(L&& lhs, R&& rhs) noexcept
{
    return detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<L>(lhs))
        <= detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<R>(rhs));
}

template <typename L, typename R
    , ENABLE_IF(
           is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<L>>::value
        || is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<R>>::value
    )
>
bool operator>=(L&& lhs, R&& rhs) noexcept
{
    return detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<L>(lhs))
        >= detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<R>(rhs));
}

template <typename L, typename R
    , ENABLE_IF(
           is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<L>>::value
        || is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<R>>::value
    )
>
bool operator<(L&& lhs, R&& rhs) noexcept
{
    return detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<L>(lhs))
         < detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<R>(rhs));
}

template <typename L, typename R
    , ENABLE_IF(
           is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<L>>::value
        || is_unique_ptr_propagate_cv<remove_cvref_t<R>>::value
    )
>
bool operator >(L&& lhs, R&& rhs) noexcept
{
    return detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<L>(lhs))
         > detail::get_underlying_unique_ptr(std::forward<R>(rhs));
}
```

Thanks for your help and reminding me that it was just a propagation issue.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that `std::unique_ptr::operator*` is defined to return a non-const reference:

```
std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const
```

Since it is an internal class, you could use plain pointers and manage the life-time explicitly, allowing you to do something like

```
span<my_type_t const> encompassing_type::get_container() const
{
     return span( m_container );
}
```

Justin proposes to use something like `span<const my_type_t>` to implement a view of constant pointers to your vector. You could e.g. do this with Boost.Range and return a range of const pointers:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;

class X {
public:
   void nonConst() {}
   void constF() const {}
};

class A{
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> v;

    public:
    A() : v(10) {}
    auto get_container() {
        return v | transformed( [](std::unique_ptr<X> const& x) -> X const* {return x.get();});
    }
};

int main()  {
A a;

auto const& v = a.get_container();
a.get_container()[0]->constF();
a.get_container()[0]->nonConst();
    return 0;
}
```

[This should be fairly efficient with an optimizing compiler.](https://godbolt.org/g/sq6tSt)

You could also switch from `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<my_type_t>>` to `boost::ptr_vector<my_type_t>`. It also assumes ownership of the elements stored by pointer, but it returns a `const_reference` in `operator[] const` such that objects cannot be modified.

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

class X {
public:
   void nonConst() {}
};

class A{
boost::ptr_vector<X> v;

    public:
    boost::ptr_vector<X> const& get_container() const {
        return v;
    }
};

int main()  {
A a;

auto const& v = a.get_container();
a.get_container()[0].nonConst();
    return 0;
}
```

This would protect the elemnents from being modified when `get_container()` returns a const reference:

> prog.cc:26:1: error: 'this' argument to member function 'nonConst' has
>   type 'const
>   boost::ptr_container_detail::reversible_ptr_container > >,
>   boost::heap_clone_allocator>::Ty_' (aka 'const X'), but function is
>   not marked const a.get_container()[0].nonConst(); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   prog.cc:9:9: note: 'nonConst' declared here    void nonConst() {}
>           ^ 1 error generated.